# Testing with RSpec, :js => true but only opens blank browser window

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec

I'm trying to write a test for my delete link.

My delete link triggers an alert confirmation first (same way delete link does when created with `scaffold`) so it relies upon `JavaScript`.

Below is my code to try and run this test using `JavaScript`.

```
feature "delete link", :js => true do
  scenario "delete a video when delete icon is clicked" do
    favorite = FactoryGirl.create(:favorite)
    visit favorites_path
    find("a.delete_icon").click
    expect(page).to_not have_content(favorite.title)
  end
end
```

What happens is that the browser window opens, but it's *blank* and it just remains open while my running test just appears to be waiting.

I have to close the browser window myself and then close the test (`Ctrl+C`).

What might I do doing wrong?

Comment: Show your `spec_helper` also.